# Not Receiving OTP from WhatsApp After Integrating Number with Facebook App for API Access

Tags: whatsapp, whatsapp-cloud-api

To obtain the WhatsApp API, I had to set up a Facebook app using my phone number.
Facebook required me to disconnect my number from WhatsApp during the integration process and then reconnect to WhatsApp afterwards.
After I removed my number from WhatsApp and integrated it with the Facebook app, I tried rejoining WhatsApp.
However, each time I attempted to do so, I didn't receive the expected OTP code, despite multiple tries with many numbers the same issue keeps.
What could be the potential cause of this issue?

However, each time I attempted to do so, I didn't receive the expected OTP code, despite multiple tries with many numbers the same issue keeps.